# SqlDataAdapter не заполняет Dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net

Пытаюсь заполнить типизированный `Dataset` для банальной Northwind, но безрезультатно. `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` возвращает количество записанных строк равное 8, но коллекция `Rows` в `Dataset` остается пустой. В чем может быть проблема?

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
{
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-ACRMMGI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Extended Northwind Database\Northwind.mdf;" +
                "Integrated Security=True;";
    cn.Open();
    string queryString = @"SELECT * FROM Categories";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString,cn);
    NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet = new NorthwindDataSet();
    int col = adapter.Fill(northwindDataSet);
    Console.WriteLine(col);
    DataTable products = northwindDataSet.Categories;
    var query =
        from prod in products.AsEnumerable()
        select prod;
    foreach (DataRow p in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p[1]+":"+p[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'adapter.Fill(northwindDataSet.Categories);' попробуйте так. Есть подозрение, что адаптер пишет не в ту таблицу, в которой вы этого ожидаете.

Comment: @kodv Помогло. Но в чем причина такого поведения? `Dataset` сгенерирован Visual Studio, почему запрос адаптер заполнял не ту таблицу?

Comment: Как SqlDataAdapter должен понять, что этим запросом вы хотели заполнить именно эту таблицу? Если бы вы использовали автоматически сгенерированный TableAdapter, то таких проблем у вас бы не было. А так нужно явно указывать таблицу, в которую хотите записать данные.